# Add new entity with relation using Spring's RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

So I have `User`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne
    private Email email;

    //getters setters, constructors
}
```

And I have `Email`, which is:

```
@Entity
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String address;

    //getters setters, constructors
}
```

They both have their own `CrudRepository`, which is annotated with `RepositoryRestResource`.

My question is: **what request body should I provide to `https://localhost:8443/users` if I want to create new user AND new email simultaneously with relation of email to that user?** I tried this, but it creates new user with `null` email_id:

```
{
    "username" : "test",
    "password" : "test",
    "email" : {
        "address" : "olol@lol.kek"
    }
}
```

Comment: try to expose a method which will return a new dummy user entity, and check how spring formats it , so send it in the same shape. Also check [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) out

Comment: How do I expose it? It's created in runtime by spring @AntJavaDev

Comment: gimme sec , will try it with your classes. I suppose that at your end it looks exactly as the posted ones

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes, only they have getter and setter methods, and default constructor and constructor with all parameters

Comment: strange , the printout gives me the same json as the one you posted. let me try to consume it with Soap UI

Comment: @AntJavaDev so you mean it successfully created both entities in db?

Comment: yep , could you post your method that accepts the user as json request and insert it in the DB with null email

Comment: @AntJavaDev no, I have a `CrudRepository` with `RepositoryRestResource` annotation, all the methods are generated automatically during runtime by Spring

Comment: yeap the problem was the missing annotation  and not the whole structure change , but the strange part is that at the time you fetch the `User` , the `Email` was null , and not at the time you inserted it. I got an exception while trying to insert it , that's why i asked you if you have posted the code at your end and also thought that you might have exposed some custom insert method

Comment: also the JSON structure is a bit different, I was trying to pass an object, but it wanted parameters for the constructor instead

Comment: nope , with your previous structure , the json in your question was the proper one. Check how the `getAll` looks like [here](https://justpaste.it/13k11). Are you using any custom exception resolver ?

Comment: or the default spring `RepositoryRestResource` produces [this](https://justpaste.it/13k1d)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Here's how it should look like, User:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Integer id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String username;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email_id")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Email email;
}
```

Email:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Integer id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String address;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "email")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private User user;

    public Email(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Thing is you have to add `@OneToOne` annotation to both and provide parameters like `mappedBy` for dependent entity and `@JoinColumn` annotation for owner. Also, it was necessary to add constructor with `String` parameter for `Email` so that it can be called during runtime (I guess in fact it's "all but **id**" constructor).

And then I just send this JSON to https://localhost:8443/users in POST request:

```
{
    "username" : "test",
    "password" : "test",
    "email" : "lolkek@cheburek.com"
}
```

And it creates both new user in database and a new email with that address for that user.